# I keep getting the Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-CLI/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/) tutorial to make a React app. I have the most updated webpack-CLI 4.2.0 in devDependencies. I looked in node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs but its not there. It only goes as far as 'bin' and it has one file in it. It's also telling me about

```
`(/Users/danielengel/Desktop/Project portfolio/watches/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)`
```

It has

```
    // webpack-cli@3.3 path : webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs
let configYargsPath;
try {
  require.resolve('webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs');
  configYargsPath = 'webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs';
} catch (e) {
  configYargsPath = 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs';
}
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-dynamic-require
require(configYargsPath)(yargs);
```

, And at the top of the file it has

```
`const yargs = require('yargs');
```

I've tried commenting out some of the code, or uncommenting in the node_modules but I know that's a bad idea. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the webpacks with NPM. I tried changing it to a regular dependency instead of dev-dependency. I tried installing it globally too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using webpack serves instead of webpack-dev-server in package.json